# How to create a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit

I have 4 labels on UIViewController. Now I want to know how can i make my current view to scrollable view using UIScrollView ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create and add these labels there. Something like this (Warning: untested)

```
UIScrollView * content = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[content setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
//Here you can add those labels to content view
[self.view addSubView:content];
```

To get scrolling to work you must specify size of the content (`setContentSize:`) larger than main view size. And don't forget to release the scroll view.

Comment: in my case i have a UIViewController that i have created programmatically usin xib file. and now i have put a scroll view using IB and all those lable on it.

Comment: You can add labels in anyway you want. The point is to add UIScrollView into view of your controller and set it's content size bigger than main view.

Comment: secondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"second" bundle:nil];
 //myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
 //[myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400, 600)];
 
 //[secondView.view addSubview:myScrollView];  [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
still not working...

Comment: Use the size of your controllers view `[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:secondView.bounds];` If you want to add labels through the Interface Builder, then you should add ScrollView in the IB and set it's size and contentSize properties.

Comment: secondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"second" bundle:nil];
 myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:secondView.bounds];      error occurs : SecondView' may not respond to '-bounds'

Comment: secondView it is a controller? If it is, you must to use `secondView.view.bounds`

Comment: ya it is n I have used secondView.view.bounds. but only scroll bar appears. page is not scrolling.

Comment: Are you sure you put your labels into UIScrollView not into UIView? Probably you have added your labels into main view and placed SctollView on top of them

Comment: see what i did... first i created simple view controller that displays 4 labels. thn i want to scroll them so i have deleted all those labels thn YES i put scroll view on current view (as u said) thn again i've put 4 labels on scroll view not to view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method:

```
-(void)scrollview
{
    UIScrollView *scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 150)];
    scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
    scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [mainScrollView addSubview:scrollview];
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(250,150);
}
```